# NextJS not working with jsmpeg/node-rtsp-stream. Trying to display RTSP stream

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, next.js, rtsp, jsmpeg

Following: https://github.com/kyriesent/node-rtsp-stream and [How to display IP camera feed from an RTSP url onto reactjs app page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290637/how-to-display-ip-camera-feed-from-an-rtsp-url-onto-reactjs-app-page) I was trying to display the RTSP stream from a CCTV but it gives me an error. `ReferenceError: document is not defined` at `scripts\jsmpeg.min.js (1:701) @ eval`

I haven't found a single implementation of this module in NextJS so I might be doing something wrong but I can't tell what. And I didn't find any better solution for NextJS.

There wasn't anything to get me out in: https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg but I might be using it wrong in here.

The rabbit hole started from this: [How can I display an RTSP video stream in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page) but things are either outdated, do not apply or I couldn't figure them out.

##### The actual question:

How can I fix the error I get? Is there an alternative to this in NextJS? I don't care how all I need is to stream the RTSP feed from a CCTV.

#### Folder Structure:

```
components
   -layout
      -Stream.js
pages
   -api
   -stream
       -[streamId].js
       -app.js
   -index.js
scripts
    -jsmpeg.min.js
```

`Stream.js` is a component in `stream/app.js` and `stream/app.js` is used in `stream/[streamId].js`

#### Client-side : `Stream.js`

```js
import JSMpeg from "../../scripts/jsmpeg.min.js";

const Stream = (props) => {
  const player = new JSMpeg.Player("ws://localhost:9999", {
    canvas: document.getElementById("video-canvas"), // Canvas should be a canvas DOM element
  });

 return (
    <Fragment>
        <canvas
          id="video-canvas"
          className={classes.canvas}
          onMouseDown={onMouseDownHandler}
        ></canvas>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

#### Server-side : `[streamId.js]`

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
const StreamCCTV = require("node-rtsp-stream");
  const streamCCTV = new StreamCCTV({
    ffmpegPath: "C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", //! remove on Ubuntu
    name: "name",
    streamUrl: "rtsp://someuser:somepassword@1.1.1.1",
    wsPort: 9999,
    ffmpegOptions: {
      // options ffmpeg flags
      "-stats": "", // an option with no neccessary value uses a blank string
      "-r": 30, // options with required values specify the value after the key
    },
  });
```

###### Edit:

I have also tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmpeg
Where i changed `Stream.js` to:

```js
import jsmpeg from 'jsmpeg';

const Stream = (props) => {
  const client = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999")
  const player = new jsmpeg(client, {
    canvas: document.getElementById("video-canvas"), // Canvas should be a canvas DOM element
  });

 return (
    <Fragment>
        <canvas
          id="video-canvas"
          className={classes.canvas}
          onMouseDown={onMouseDownHandler}
        ></canvas>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Now the error is: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)

Comment: @juliomalves I'd say it might but I can't afford to test it anymore. My solution now was to give up on node for RTSP handling and made another server in Flask and handled the stream there.

Comment: I am trying to have this solution in python as well. May I use your flask solution?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work with two solutios:

1. Download `jsmpeg.min.js` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg/master/jsmpeg.min.js) and add it to the same directory as your component (or to any other desired directory).
2. Change the first part of the file from `var JSMpeg...` to `export const JSMpeg...`
3. Add a component with the following content:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

const StreamPlayer = () => {
    
    const streamRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const { JSMpeg } = require('./jsmpeg.min.js')
        const player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
            canvas: streamRef.current
        })
    }, [])

return <canvas ref={streamRef} id="stream-canvas"></canvas>
}
```

### NOTE

I am not sure if it is ok to use `require` in `useEffect` but since `JSMpeg` is using `document` and `window` objects, they have to be imported after they are loaded.\

###### The second way

to do this is a less modular way but doesn't include this potentially bad practice:

1. Download `jsmpeg.min.js` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg/master/jsmpeg.min.js) and add it to the `/public` directory of your Nextjs project.
2. Add a component with the following content:

```
import Script from 'next/script'

const StreamPlayer = () => {

return (
    <>
        <canvas id="stream-canvas"></canvas>
        <Script src="jsmpeg.min.js" id="jsmpeg"></Script>
    </>
)}
```

3. Then, at the end of the `jsmpeg.min.js` I added:

```
player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
    canvas: document.getElementById('stream-canvas')
})
```

Comment: Instead of using next/sript, I'm using import() inside useEffect, tho. Thanks, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

jsmpeg can play mpeg1 only. please use ffmpeg with mpegts format stream